# Testing intersection of two regular languages

Tags: parsing, finite-automata, automata

I want to test whether two languages have a string in common.  Both of these languages are from a subset of regular languages described below and I only need to know whether there exists a string in both languages, not produce an example string.

The language is specified by a glob-like string like

> `/foo/**/bar/*.baz`

where `**` matches 0 or more characters, and `*` matches zero or more characters that are not `/`, and all other characters are literal.

Any ideas?

thanks,
mike

EDIT:

I implemented something that seems to perform well, but have yet to try a correctness proof.   You can see the [source](http://code.google.com/p/prebake/source/browse/trunk/code/src/org/prebake/core/Glob.java#549) and [unit tests](http://code.google.com/p/prebake/source/browse/trunk/code/tests/org/prebake/core/GlobTest.java#151)

Comment: What language will you use to perform the check? You are probably going to need to write a test bed for this. If you could post a fairly complete test bed it would help.

Comment: This will need to run in JS.  I will of course have to write a testbed.  I found a useful subset for which I can compute intersection efficiently by doing some tricks.  The useful subset is one where * and ** can only appear at the start or directly after a /, and a / cannot be adjacent to another /.

That means that I never need to worry whether *foo* can match boo*baz -- I have to do backtracking, but not a ridiculous amounts since I can always turn text following a * or ** into a suffix check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Build FAs `A` and `B` for both languages, and construct the "intersection FA" `AnB`.  If `AnB` has at least one accepting state accessible from the start state, then there is a word that is in both languages.

Constructing `AnB` could be tricky, but I'm sure there are FA textbooks that cover it.  The approach I would take is:

- The states of `AnB` is the cartesian product of the states of `A` and `B` respectively.  A state in `AnB` is written `(a, b)` where `a` is a state in `A` and `b` is a state in `B`.
- A transition `(a, b) ->r (c, d)` (meaning, there is a transition from `(a, b)` to `(c, d)` on symbol `r`) exists iff `a ->r c` is a transition in `A`, and `b ->r d` is a transition in `B`.
- `(a, b)` is a start state in `AnB` iff `a` and `b` are start states in `A` and `B` respectively.
- `(a, b)` is an accepting state in `AnB` iff each is an accepting state in its respective FA.

This is all off the top of my head, and hence completely unproven!

Comment: Well, this is a well-documented construction called the Cartesian Product Machine, many people beat you to this, and it is a well-documented and correct method to get an FA recognizing the intersection of languages recognized by other FAs. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a quick search and this problem is decidable (aka can be done), but I don't know of any good algorithms to do it. One is solution is:

1. Convert both regular expressions to NFAs A and B
2. Create a NFA, C, that represents the intersection of A and B.
3. Now try every string from 0 to the number of states in C and see if C accepts it (since if the string is longer it must repeat states at one point).

I know this might be a little hard to follow but this is only way I know how.