# Is there a way to check if two regexps can match the same string?

Tags: algorithm

I have two regexps. I need to determine if it is possible to build string of given length that matches these two regexps simultaneously. I need algorithm to do that.

String's length wouldn't exceed 20 characters.

Comment: Don't be shy. Show us the 2 regexps

Comment: It is program, so these two regexps would be different in every run of this program.

Comment: If you want to *build* a string, you can do the following if you have the two DFAs for the RegExes: use the cartesian product of the automata and search a path from the initial state to the accepting state via a graph search algorithm.

Comment: @frp, your assignment must have regexp constraints otherwise the solution - while possible - will be pretty complex (and the way you ask the question suggests you are not looking for  a fully [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)  compliant algorithm)

Comment: The first one is usual regexp (without backreferences and "hard features" of PCRE). The second one can be simplified to comprise of only dots and letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. For perl compatible regular expressions (pcre), this is not generally possible, as they are turing complete: you cannot even be sure that matching always terminates.

For the original, "clean" form of reguler languages as defined in the Chomsky-hierarchy, it is known that they are closed under intersection, this is already discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338716/testing-intersection-of-two-regular-languages#2338952).

As soon as you have the [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) for the intersection, it is easy to check whether any string matches it - if thera is a path from the start to the end of your NFA, then the string for this path is the string you are searching for, for DFAs, an algorithm is given [here](http://faculty.ycp.edu/~dhovemey/fall2010/cs340/lecture/lecture12.html), it should be simple to adapt it to NFAs.

Comment: practical example in c++ for DFA/NFA flow.http://code.google.com/p/regexpparser/